# Probability of $n$ successes in a row at the $k$-th Bernoulli trial... geometric?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

If one has Bernoulli trials with success probability $p$, then it makes sense that the probability of the first success observed to be at trial number $k$ be given by

$$(1-p)^{k-1} p.$$

But how would we approach the same problem if the probability we are after is the probability of getting the first occurrence of two successes in a row at the $k$-th trial? In other words, for trial $k$ to be a success, with trial $k-1$ being a success and with no other occurrence of two successes in a row before that? In general what if we want the first $n$ successes in a row? I can do this with some counting if $p = 1/2$ but my counting argument (a requirement on the sequence of first $k-3$ trials, plus enforcing failure on the $k-2$ and then enforcing two successes in a row) breaks down if $p \neq 1/2$.  This shouldn't be too hard as it seems very similar in nature to the geometric distribution.

Thanks.

Comment: "with no other occurrence of two successes in a row before that".  That's the more complicated part.

Comment: I had asked a similar question here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/303960/119261.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An analysis of the $n=2$ case is below.  Let me explain why the general $n$ case is going to be ugly, bordering on impossible.

Let $P_k$ denote the probability that $n$ consecutive successes occur at trial $k$ for the first time.  Since seeing a failure "restarts" the process, $P_k$ must satisfy the following recurrence relation for $k > n$:

$$P_k = q P_{k-1} + pq P_{k-2} + p^2 q P_{k-3}+ \cdots + p^{n-1} q P_{k-n}.$$
This is an $n$th order linear difference equation with constant coefficients.  Thus its solution is of the form $P_k = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i r_i^k$, where the $r_i$s are the roots of the equation $$x^n - q x^{n-1} - pq x^{n-2} - \cdots - p^{n-1} q = 0.$$  So an explicit form for $P_k$ would require us to solve this equation for general $p$ and $q$.  That is not likely to be possible in closed form.  In fact, as we see below, the case when $n=2$ already gets quite ugly.  The recurrence relation with the initial conditions $P_0 = P_1 = \cdots = P_{n-1} = 0, P_n = p^n$, might be the best we can do.

---

(*Original answer.*)  For the $n = 2$ case, let $X$ denote the trial in which we see the second consecutive success for the first time.  Let $P_k$ denote $P(X=k)$.  I'll give

1. An exact expression for $P_k$ via the solution to a recurrence for $P_k$,
2. A binomial sum expression for $P_k$ via a combinatorial argument,
3. The probability generating function $G(z)$ for $X$,
4. $E[X]$, and
5. $Var[X]$.

The method used to find the exact expression for $P_k$ and the method for finding the probability generating function can be extended to the general $n$ case, but this will get uglier and uglier as $n$ increases.

---

**Expression 1.**  Since, except for SS, any sequence counted under $P_k$ must either start with F or with SF, we have the recurrence relation $P_k = q P_{k-1} + pq P_{k-2}$, for $k \geq 3$, with initial conditions $P_0 = P_1 = 0$, $P_2 = p^2$.  This is a [second-order linear difference equation with constant coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_equation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients), and thus the solution is $P_k = A r_1^k + B r_2^k,$ where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of the auxiliary equation $x^2 - q x - pq = 0$, and $A$ and $B$ are found via the initial conditions.  Crunching through the algebra, we get, for $k \geq 1$,
$$P_k = \frac{p^2\left(\left(q + \sqrt{q^2+4pq}\right)^{k-1} - \left(q - \sqrt{q^2+4pq}\right)^{k-1}\right)}{2^{k-1}\sqrt{q^2+4pq}}.$$

Note that if $p = q = \frac{1}{2}$ the recurrence reduces to $P_k = \frac{1}{2} P_{k-1} + \frac{1}{4} P_{k-2}$.  Thus, for $k \geq 1$, $P_k = \frac{F_{k-1}}{2^k}$, where $F_k$ is the $k$th Fibonacci number.

---

**Expression 2.**

We know that the last two trials have to be successes.  Suppose, then, that there are $j$ successes in the first $k-2$ trials.  Since every one of these $j$ successes must be followed by a failure, we need the number of ways to place $j$ times in $k-2$ locations a $p$ followed by a $q$.  Since $pq$ must be treated as a pair, though, this is equivalent to the number of ways to place $j$ individual items into $k-2-j$ locations.  The number of ways to do this is $\binom{k-2-j}{j}$, and so the probability that there are $j$ successes in the first $k-2$ trials followed by successes in the last two trials is $p^2 \binom{k-2-j}{j} (pq)^j q^{k-2-2j} = p^2 \binom{k-2-j}{j} p^j q^{k-2-j}$.  Summing over all possible values of $j$ gives us
$$P_k = p^2 \sum_{j = 0}^{k-2} \binom{k-2-j}{j} p^j q^{k-2-j}.$$

If $p = q = \frac{1}{2}$, we get, once again, $P_k = \frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{j = 0}^{k-2} \binom{k-2-j}{j} = \frac{F_{k-1}}{2^k}$, where the last step follows from the "sum of the shallow diagonals" property of Pascal's triangle.  (See MathWorld's [entry on Pascal's triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PascalsTriangle.html), Eq. 16.)

---

**The probability generating function, expected value, and variance.**

We can also find the [probability generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function).  This is $$G(z) = \frac{p^2 z^2}{1-qz-pqz^2}.$$

A basic property of probability generating functions says that $P_k$ can be calculated via $P_k = G^{(k)}(0)/k!$.

If $p = q = \frac{1}{2}$, then we have $G(z) =  \frac{(z/2)^2}{1-(z/2)-(z/2)^2} = z/2 F(z/2)$, where $F(z) = \frac{z}{1-z-z^2}$, the generating function for the Fibonacci numbers.  Thus, once again, we see that $P_k = \frac{F_{k-1}}{2^k}$ in this case.

To derive the generating function, consider the "infinite sum" of possible ways to obtain two successes in a row in the last two trials:
$$SS + FSS + FFSS + SFSS + FFFSS + FSFSS + SFFSS + \cdots.$$

Since, until the last two trials, an F can be followed by an S or an F, while an S must be followed by an F, every term in this sum can be decomposed uniquely into the product of terms chosen from {F, SF} followed by SS.  Thus we can (formally) express this infinite sum as 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (F + SF)^k SS = \frac{SS}{1 - F - SF}.$$
Taking $S = pz$ and $F = qz$ (i.e., count one trial for each success and one for each failure) gives the generating function $G(z)$.

Finally, we can use the probability generating function to calculate moments.  For example, since the expected value is $G'(1^-)$ and the variance is $G''(1^-) + G'(1^-) - [G'(1^-)]^2$, a little calculus and a lot of simplifying shows that  $$E[X] = \frac{1}{p^2} + \frac{1}{p}$$
and $$Var[X] = \frac{1}{p^4} + \frac{2}{p^3} - \frac{2}{p^2} - \frac{1}{p}.$$

Comment: Wow this was much harder than I thought. Very clever generating function solution thanks!

Comment: I can't believe this answer only has 3 upvotes...

Answer (score 0):

For any n the exact answer can be found in the following papers

Evgeny Khorov, Anton Kiryanov, Andrey Lyakhov, Dmitry Ostrovsky. Analytical Study of Neighborhood Discovery and Link Management in OLSR. //IFIP Wireless Days 2012, Dublin, 2012. http://www.gta.ufrj.br/ftp/gta/TechReports/wd2012/1569655727.pdf

Evgeny Khorov, Anton Kiryanov, Andrey Lyakhov, Alexander Safonov. Analytical Study of Link Management in IEEE 802.11s Mesh Networks //International Symposium on Wireless Communication Systems (ISWCS). France, 2012. P. 786-790 http://khorov.iitp.ru/eng/science/papers/2012-khorov-mpmp.pdf