# About one generating function

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Initially, I have the following problem: find $$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(−1)^{n−k}4^k{n+k+1 \choose 2k}.$$ I thought, if I found the function $g_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n+k \choose 2k}x^k$, the answer would be $(-1)^ng_{n+1}(-4)$. I tried to factorize ${n + k \choose 2k}$ to ${n+k \choose k}{n \choose k}/{2k \choose k}$. It is known that $$(1-x)^{-n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{n + k \choose k}x^k,$$ $$(1-4x)^{-1/2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{2k \choose k}x^k,$$ $$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}x^k.$$ I have tried to combine these formulae, but nothing interesting has been found yet.

Comment: Have you tried out some small values of $n$ to see if there's a pattern?

Comment: (It looked to me like there was an obvious pattern starting with $n=0,1,2$.)

Answer (score 7):

Your sum can be rewritten like so:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (-1)^{n-k} 4^k \binom{n+k+1}{2k} &= \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (-1)^{n-k} 4^k \binom{n+1+k}{n+1-k}  \\
&= \sum_{j \geq 0} (-1)^{j-1} 4^{n+1-j} \binom{2(n+1)-j}{j} \\
&= \sum_{j \geq 0} (-1)^{j-1} 4^{m/2-j} \binom{m-j}{j} \\
&= - \frac{1}{2^m}\sum_{j \geq 0} (-1)^j 4^{m-j} \binom{m-j}{j}, \\
\end{align}$$
where we switched indices twice via $k = n+1-j$ and $m = 2n+2$.   So what we need is the bivariate generating function of the sum 
$$G_m(x,y) = \sum_{j \geq 0} \binom{m-j}{j} x^j y^{m-j}.$$
(Note that when $x = y= 1$ this gives $F_{m+1}$, the $m+1$ Fibonacci number.)

I considered this generating function in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73772/2370).  In particular, $G(x,y)$ satisfies the recurrence $$G_m(x,y) = y G_{m-1}(x,y) + xy G_{m-2}(x,y)$$ with initial conditions $G_0(x,y) = 1$, $G_1(x,y) = y$.  With $x = -1, y = 4$, we need to solve $$G_m = 4 G_{m-1} -4 G_{m-2},$$
which has auxiliary equation $z^2 - 4z + 4 = 0$.  There is a double root at $z = 2$, and so the general solution is $G_m = A2^m + Bm 2^m$.  Subbing in the initial conditions, we have $$G_m = 2^m + m 2^m.$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{-1}{2^m} \sum_{j \geq 0} (-1)^j 4^{m-j} \binom{m-j}{j} = \frac{-1}{2^m} (2^m + m 2^m) = -1 -m.$$
Since $m = 2n+2$, subbing back in terms of $n$ gives us the answer you're after:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (-1)^{n-k} 4^k \binom{n+k+1}{2k} = -1 -(2n+2) = -2n-3.$$

---

More generally, the bivariate generating function is $$G_m(x,y) = \frac{\left(y + \sqrt{y^2+4xy}\right)^{m+1} - \left(y - \sqrt{y^2+4xy}\right)^{m+1}}{2^{m+1}\sqrt{y^2+4xy}},$$
provided, of course, that $y^2 + 4xy \neq 0$.  However, this is precisely the case that the OP's question falls in, and so we have to go to the recurrence relation to find the solution.  ([Binet's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio) for the Fibonacci numbers is obtained by setting $x = y = 1$, so this is a generalization of that formula.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {n+1+k\choose 2k} (-1)^{n-k} 4^k
= (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {n+1+k\choose n+1-k} (-4)^k.$$

Start from
$${n+1+k\choose n+1-k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+2-k}} (1+z)^{n+1+k} \; dz.$$

This yields the following expression for the sum
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \frac{1}{z^{n+2-k}} (1+z)^{n+1+k} 
\times (-4)^k\; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{z^{n+2}}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (1+z)^k \times z^k 
\times (-4)^k\; dz.$$

Observe that the defining integral of the binomial coefficient is zero
when $n+2  -k < 1.$  This condition  is precisely $n-k  < -1$ or  $k >
n+1.$ Therefore we may extend the sum to infinity.

We thus have
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{z^{n+2}}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty  (1+z)^k \times z^k 
\times (-4)^k\; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{z^{n+2}}
\frac{1}{1+4(1+z)z} \; dz.
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{z^{n+2}}
\frac{1}{(1+2z)^2} \; dz.$$

Therefore the value of the integral is given by
$$(-1)^n [z^{n+1}] \frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{(1+2z)^2}
= (-1)^n \sum_{q=0}^{n+1} {n+1\choose n+1-q} (q+1) (-2)^q
\\= (-1)^n \sum_{q=0}^{n+1} {n+1\choose q} (q+1) (-2)^q.$$

Recall that $$(z (1+z)^n)'
= \sum_{q=0}^n {n \choose q} (q+1) z^q
= (1+z)^n + nz(1+z)^{n-1}$$
so that the end result for the sum is
$$(-1)^n \times ((-1)^{n+1} - 2(n+1)(-1)^n)
= -1 - 2(n+1) = -3 - 2n.$$

A trace as to when this method appeared on MSE and by whom starts at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792567/).

The reader is invited to try this method on the binomial coefficient
$${n+1+k\choose 2k}$$ and examine carefully what happens.