# Evaluate: $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-4)^k\frac{{n+k \choose 2k}}{ak+b}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

From this [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3556070/sum-of-binomial-series-with-alternate-terms/3557200#3557200):

How does one find the closed form for $(1)?$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-4)^k\frac{{n+k \choose 2k}}{ak+b}=F(a,b)\tag1$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-4)^k\frac{{n+k \choose n-k}}{ak+b}=F(a,b)\tag2$$

This one is from the [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3556070/sum-of-binomial-series-with-alternate-terms/3557200#3557200):

$F(0,1)=(-1)^n(2n+1)$

We got these two:

$F(1,1)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

$F(2,1)=\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$

Comment: Do you have reason to expect that there is a closed form?

Comment: So far we got three particular results, so I suspect there should be a closed-form, but I doubt it is simple.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha mostly just returns hypergeometric series or "difference roots", but it gives interesting results for [$F(2,3)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%28-4%29%5Ek+binom%28n%2Bk%2C2k%29+%2F+%282k%2B3%29+for+k%3D0..n) and [$F(2,5)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%28-4%29%5Ek+binom%28n%2Bk%2C2k%29+%2F+%282k%2B5%29+for+k%3D0..n&dataset=).

Comment: Your $F(1,1)$ seems to be incorrect, it should be $F(1,1)=\frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)-1}{2n(n+1)}$ (this also implies values for all $F(a,a)=\frac{1}{a}F(1,1)$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a closed form as follow :

$$ F(a,b)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1(-4t)^{ak+b-1}\binom{n+k}{2k}dt \right) $$

Finite sum

$$ F(a,b)=\left( \int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^n(-4t)^{ak+b-1}\binom{n+k}{n-k}dt \right) $$

Then using the *coefficient extraction function* $[X^i]$ for a given $i$.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n(-4t)^{ak+b-1}\binom{n+k}{n-k}
& = \sum_{k=0}^n(-4t)^{ak+b-1}[X^{n-k}](1+X)^{n+k} \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^n(-4t)^{ak+b-1}[X^n]z^k(1+X)^{n+k} \\
&  = [X^n](1+X)^n(-t)^{a+b-1}\sum_{k=0}^n(-4^at^a)^{k}X^k(1+X)^{k} \\
& = [X^n](1+X)^n(-t)^{a+b-1}\dfrac{1-(-4^at^aX(1+X))^{n+1}}{1+4^at^aX(1+X)} \\
&= [X^n](1+X)^n(-t)^{a+b-1}\dfrac{1}{1+4^at^aX(1+X)} \\
&=[X^n](-t)^{a+b-1}\dfrac{(1+X)^{n-1}}{1+4^at^aX} \\
& = [X^n](-t)^{a+b-1}(1+X)^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^i(4^at^aX)^i \\
& = (-t)^{a+b-1}\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^i[X^{n-i}](1+X)^{n-1}(4^at^a)\\
& = (-t)^{a+b-1}\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i}(4^at^a)^i\\
& = (-t)^{a+b-1}(1-4^at^a)^{n-1}\\
\end{align*}

From here the exercise can be ended.

**Credits**

This answer is inspired from the work in the answer here : [sum of binomial series with alternate terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3556070/sum-of-binomial-series-with-alternate-terms).