# Probability of finding at least $k$ consecutive heads in $N$ coin tosses?

Tags: probability, reference-request

There are quite a few topics on this question already but I couldn't find a well-explained solution. Please point me towards some relevant literature or theory to analyze this problem.

[$K$ consecutive heads with a biased coin?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329938/k-consecutive-heads-with-a-biased-coin)

[Probability of tossing a biased coin without having k heads consecutively in a row](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281195/probability-of-tossing-a-biased-coin-without-having-k-heads-consecutively-in-a-r)

[Probability of tossing a fair coin with at least $k$ consecutive heads](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234062/probability-of-tossing-a-fair-coin-with-at-least-k-consecutive-heads)

Thanks.

Comment: I think this would be a duplicate except that you're asking for relevant literature or theory; as such I've added the `reference-request` tag.

Comment: "I couldn't find a well-explained solution" Users Sasha and joriki will be delighted. (Unrelated: several other MSE pages answer the same question in details.)

Comment: Feller, "An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications, Volume 1, 3rd Edition", section XIII.7.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two methods that can solve this problem. Both are discussed in detail in this question:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21825/probability-over-multiple-blocks-of-events